# Different number of notifications for different Office365 accounts when a tentative event is approved

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We're integrating our platform with some company's Office365 Exchange, they have rooms that need approval for the meetings. So, when somebody creates an appointment with one of those rooms this event will have  "Tentative" in the GetItem response. After the event is approved, with push subscription enabled for the room, I get 2 notifications: cancellation of the tentative event and creation of the accepted event with different event ID.

I created another Office365 account for testing purposes and added a room that requires meetings to be approved also. When I create an appointment with that room, the room's event also has  "Tentative". But when the room's delegate approves the tentative event, I get only one subscription notification, that the event was just updated and the event ID remains the same.

I checked the rooms configurations and didn't find any significant difference except delegate names and some other fields with users.
The question, what Exchange settings are responsible for this different notifications behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: different versions or patch levels of Exchange on the back end?